# Looking for jQuery plugin for rounded corners that supports IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-6, rounded-corners

Does anyone know a jQuery plugin for creating rounded corners for `div` elements **that supports also IE6** ? I'm interested in a cross browsers solution, and the plugins that I saw so far didn't work well with IE6. Thank you very much !

Comment: Make it look *decent* with IE6, not the bells and whistles.  While the **functionality** should be there, don't worry about the look as much. If they're using a decade old browser...well, then they get a decade old look.

Comment: and don't use javascript (even jQuery) for initial styling. if css can't do it, just don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a jQuery plugin -- use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

This is an IE-specific script that implements standard CSS `border-radius` in older versions of IE (IE6 - IE8).

It doesn't rely on any other libraries, and it works great in IE6.

Answer (score 4):

If you're gonna do small fancy things, you can't spend half a week looking for ways to make it compatible with ancient (and broken) browsers. If you actually wanna account for IE6, then you need to have pictures for borders or you have to accept that IE6 will render them square. There's no shame in having older browsers render things differently, as long as your content is still visible. The main thing is the content, isn't it?

Part of my point is that the IE graphics plugins, especially on older browsers (because they usually come with older hardware) are slow, and will annoy users more than make them admire your design.

Comment: OK, I accept that in IE6 the corners will not be rounded. The problem is that I get an error message pop-up rather than just making the corners square. Should I check in this case which browser is in use and apply the rounded corners jQuery code only for the supported browsers ?

Comment: just use IE conditional comments `<!--[if IE 6]><script src="ie6.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using this plugin on my blog: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/

It really depends on how your page is structured, as this plugin creates an image for each corner - which can sometimes mess up the layout.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most of the people here, I have seen my team mates wasting half of their sprints designing things for IE6 so that the site looks similar. The solution that always used to fascinate me was that have a gracefully degraded solution which is simpler for IE6. but first of all you should use your analytics to figure out what % of your target audience will use IE6. And decide the amount of degradation for your design based on those numbers.